# The use of map when the function that map is used on has arrays of inputs

Tags: julia

Julia's "higher-order" function "map" looks very useful. But while it is easy to understand how it can be used on functions that have one input, it is not obvious how map can be used when the function has multiple inputs, and when each these may be arrays. I would like discover how map is used in that situation.

Suppose I have the following function:

```
function randomSample(items, weights)
sample(items, Weights(weights))
end
```

## Example:

```
Pkg.add("StatsBase")
using StatsBase
randomSample([1,0],[0.5, 0.5])
```

How can map be used here? I have tried something like:

```
items = [1 0;1 0;1 0]
weights = [1 0;0.5 0.5;0.75 0.25]

map(randomSample(items,weights))
```

In the example above, I would expect Julia to output a 3 by 1 array of integers (from the items), each row being either 0 or 1 depending on the corresponding weights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case when `items` and `weights` are `Matrix` you can use the `eachrow` function like this:

```
map(randomSample, eachrow(items), eachrow(weights))
```

If you are on Julia version earlier than 1.1 you can write:

```
map(i -> randomSample(items[i, :], weights[i, :]), axes(items, 1))
```

or

```
map(i -> randomSample(view(items,i, :), view(weights, i, :)), axes(items, 1))
```

(the latter avoids allocations)

However, in practice I would probably define `items` and `weights` as vectors of vectors:

```
items = [[1, 0],[1, 0],[1, 0]]
weights = [[1, 0], [0.5, 0.5], [0.75, 0.25]]
```

and then you can simply write:

```
map(randomSample, items, weights)
```

or

```
randomSample.(items, weights)
```

The reason for my preference is the following:

- it is conceptually clearer what is the structure of your data
- vector of vectors is easier to mutate (e.g. you can `push!` a new entry at the end)
- vector of vectors can be ragged if needed
- in some cases it might be a bit faster (iterating by rows in Julia is not optimal as it uses column-major indexing; of course you can fix it in your `Matrix` approach by assuming that you store your data columnwise not colwise as you currently do)

(this is not a very strong preference and you can probably choose whatever is more convenient to you)

Comment: Kaminski, using Juliabox, I get the error "UndefVarError: eachrow not defined."

Comment: `eachrow` requires Julia 1.1. I will add a comment what to do in an older version of Julia in the answer.